# How to convert nvarchar to numeric in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert `nvarchar` to `numeric`?

I got this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    strIpay88Amt, 
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), strIpay88Amt) AS iPay
FROM
    tblCurrTrxMaster
```

Comment: And what are the **values** stored in the `strIpay88Amt` column? And why - if it's a *amount* - is this a `nvarchar` type to begin with?? You should **always** use the most appropriate datatype - and if you have an **Amount**, that's certainly **NOT** `nvarchar` !

Comment: you are correct, but i receive the value in 'nvarchar' thats why i use 'nvarchar'. but i want to convert the amount value to 'numeric' to bring the value to other application.

Comment: the value in that column 1.00 and NULL

Comment: Those values convert to `numeric` just fine - there must be other values that you're trying to convert that cause this error to be thrown..... the only reason could be that your "locale" uses the comma `,` as decimal separator, while the strings send you a dot (`.`). Can you try this: `SELECT CAST(N'1.0' AS NUMERIC(18,2))` does that work on your server, or throw an error? Next replace the `1.0` with a `1,0` and try again

Comment: @marc_c if value is 1.0 it wiil cast but if use( `,`) error is happened.

Comment: 1.0 is not a fix value. i will receive any numbers with this format -> 0.00 and NULL value.

Comment: @neginmotalebi: that **depends** on your locale's number format.....

Comment: Thank you for the answer. its work. i try with other table which no NULL value.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are string values in strIpay88Amt column. 
You can use following to convert only numeric values.

```
select cast(strIpay88Amt as numeric) from tblCurrTrxMaster 
where ISNUMERIC(strIpay88Amt) = 1
```

And following to fetch string values.

```
select strIpay88Amt from tblCurrTrxMaster where ISNUMERIC(strIpay88Amt) = 0
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is notoriously bad and returns a lot of "false positives" - I'd much rather use the `try_cast` function that handles this much more reliably ....

Answer (score 1):

There **must be** some entry in your table that is **NOT** a valid number and thus your conversion fails - and rightfully so.

So in order to find these entries, you can try this:

```
SELECT 
    strIpay88Amt, 
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), strIpay88Amt) AS iPay
FROM
    dbo.tblCurrTrxMaster 
WHERE
    TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), strIpay88Amt) IS NULL
```

This will use the `TRY_CONVERT` function to *attempt* the conversion - and with this `WHERE` clause, you'll only get back all those entries that **could not** be converted to a valid `NUMERIC`.

While `NULL` will "convert" properly to a numeric, an **empty string** (`''`) for instance will already cause an error......

Answer (score 0):

try cast syntax:

```
 SELECT strIpay88Amt, CAST(strIpay88Amt AS NUMERIC) AS iPay FROM tblCurrTrxMaster
```

Comment: its still same error -> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Are you sure that all of your data in this column is numeric?

Comment: No.Actually , i want to convert nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: It's happened because you have character in data list of this column.make sure all of data of this column are numeric and then use this syntax.

Comment: all data in that column is nvarchar. i want to convert it in numeric.

Comment: I understand what you say; I want to know is this column's data include just numeric value and null value or not?